# How can I store ActiveDirectory credentials for MS SQL Server integrated security in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

The application in question needs insert access to a database table, and the requirement is that every user of the application will have access to this insert without authentication, but SQL Server will require authentication from one AD/Windows user/password which is to be stored in the application.

Is there a best practices or recommended way to set this up?  I'm having trouble finding a solution.

Note:  This is not specifically Integrated Security as the database shouldn't care who is using the application.

Comment: user application is different from AD user? And you need user who run application to auth with sql?

Comment: the web application (really just a single form that inserts) is not going to require authentication in any way

Comment: any user without authenticate who have access to web application can insert in db table?

Comment: yes that is their plan

Comment: web application is perhaps a strong word, really it's just saving a submitted form to a database

Comment: and that user (who open the browser) is always an AD user?
if the answer is "yes", then you can use that user (user who ran the browser).
if not, then you can try with Credentials in SQL Server... for you application.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht43wsex.aspx

Comment: They are not always an AD user.  I will look into your link.  Also looking into ASP.NET impersonation